# How do I connect my ipad to my wifi

Tags: wireless-networking

I turned on my WiFi and my iPad has not been able to see it. I tried using an Android phone to connect to my WiFi and it connected. I tried restarting the iPad several times, but still it cant see any available WiFi networks.

Comment: Questions about electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones are off-topic, except insofar as they interface with your computer, See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). 


Try asking on http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plane mode on?
Sometimes the wifi card in apple products stops working(has happened to me).
What you chould do is call apple support and check with them.
And if support can't help you try do get a refund.

BUT before try to connect the ipad to your computer and open itunes and restart the ipad.